# I am getting an System.NullReferenceException error I cannot understand

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting this error:

> "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_lmzivtl2.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional
>   information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

And here is the code I was using:

```
    @model IEnumerable<PtExamen.Models.Teste>

   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Teste";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   <h2>Teste</h2>
    @{foreach (var item in Model )
    {
       <p>
          &nbsp     @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Descriere)  <br> <br>
          &nbsp &nbsp  <a href="@ViewBag.NumeFisier" target="_blank">@ViewBag.test</a>)                                
       </p>
   }
   }
```

I do not understand why this error came to be since i have used similar examples of this so far and I did not get this problem. Any help, explanation would be great. Thanks in advance!

I used something similar elsewhere and this error did not take place and I cant really find what made this part of the code not cause any problems and the other did. Here is another place I used something similar but I did not have any problems:

```
@model IEnumerable<PtExamen.Models.Capitole>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}




<div>
    <div id="div-1">
     <p><h2> @ViewBag.MateriaSelectata.ToUpper()</h2></p>
    </div>

    <div id="div-1a">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                string materiasel = ViewBag.MateriaSelectata;
                int cidSelectat = Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.cidSelectat);
               <p>@Html.ActionLink(item.den_capitol, "Index", new { materia = item.disciplina , cid = item.id }) <br></p>
```

Comment: Where does the error happen?

Comment: Hmm, why are you using e.g. `ViewBag.Descriere` in the foreach? Don't you want to use `item.Descriere`?

Comment: It is telling me that "Model" in the foreach i used is the problem.

Comment: Luaan, I know that isn't the way to do it but i had to bring the data from another model/controller and i found it easier to move it around using a ViewBag

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hmm, i do not think so. Since the problem here is that it basically says that "Model" is null/undeclared but that cant be the case. Thats why i cant understand what is with this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere in your dll (App_Web_lmzivtl2.dll) you referencing a null object or you forgot to instantiate it. i.e object myobject=new object();
then give myobject a value.

Comment: Thanks :D. I thougth so too, but then i saw that the dll the error specifies changes every time, 1 time it was App_Web_p2hpwcbl.dll  another App_Web_lmzivtl2.dll. So i dont really know where to go to fix it.

Comment: I have found the problem The Return in my controller was bringing back something that was indeed null, thanks for making me realise the problem was of such a silly nature :)